# May I know name of artist (Characters identified: 查那晨製)

Tags: character-identification, seal

Need help in reading the seal to identify name of teapot potter . Would like to find his kiln and if his teapots and handmade. Thank you.[image]

Comment: The characters are, from upper-right, lower-right, upper-left, lower-left: 查那䢅（晨）制（製）. I don't know the reading order though, and can't make out a Chinese-sounding name from the characters 查, 那, and 晨 in any order.